# iOS 4.3 crashes when uploading video

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have an iPhone app that uploads images and video to a web service using ASIHTTPRequest. Everything works great on devices running iOS 5, but crashes on 4.3 and below devices after returning from the UIImagePickerController. The video is compressed bu=y the picker, then the app crashes. Below is the code from the -(void)imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method, and also from the method that post the video to the server and a method that captures an image from the video to use as a thumbnail. Any ideas on what's causing the crashes in 4.3?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

self.mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

 if ([self.mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    // Get asset to use for orientation determination   
    AVAsset *myAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];

    self.videoOrientation = [self UIInterfaceOrientationToString:[self orientationForTrack:myAsset]];

    UIImage *videoThumbnail = [self getVideoThumbnailFromAVAsset:myAsset];
    self.photoImageView.image = videoThumbnail;

    self.videoData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}

-(UIImage*)getVideoThumbnailFromAVAsset:(AVAsset *)myAsset {
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:myAsset];

Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([myAsset duration]);
CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);
NSError *error = nil;
CMTime actualTime;
UIImage *myImage;

CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

if (halfWayImage != NULL) {
    myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
    CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);
}
return myImage;
}

- (void)postMessage:(id)sender {

self.uploadButton.enabled = NO;
[self.descriptionTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.titleTextField resignFirstResponder];

NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *sessionKey = [settings stringForKey: @"sessionKey"];

// build URL for request
NSString *baseURL;
NSString *endPoint;

// code here that creates the url component strings baseURL and endPoint

NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURL, endPoint];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.postFormat = ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat;

NSString *teamIDStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.teamID intValue]];

[request setPostValue:sessionKey forKey:@"sessionKey"];
[request setPostValue:teamIDStr forKey:@"TeamID"];   
[request setPostValue:titleTextField.text forKey:@"lessonName"];
[request setPostValue:descriptionTextField.text forKey:@"lessonDesc"];
[request setPostValue:self.videoOrientation forKey:@"videoOrientation"];

//create video file name
NSDate *date1=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"hhmm"];
NSString *valuestr = [formatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
NSString *moviename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%@.mov", valuestr];

[request setData:self.videoData withFileName:moviename andContentType:@"video/quicktime" forKey:@"file1.mov"];

[request setUploadProgressDelegate:self.progressBar];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
self.progressBar.hidden = NO;
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:600];
[request startAsynchronous];

}
```

Comment: does it crash in the simulator, and could you find where it crashes? then you'd probably be able to answer the question :)

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to add videos to the simulator. When I put them in the directory where the saved photos stores images, they don't show up in the UIImagePickerVirewController

Comment: `NSLog(@"Documents: %@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]);`    maybe?

Comment: can i see the code to get the video orientation? and how to fix the thumbnail?

Answer (score 4):

SImple answer to this issue: The AVAsset class method

```
+ (id)assetWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
```

is not available before iOS 5.0. You must use the concrete subclass AVURLAsset to instantiate an AVAsset for iOS 4.0 and 4.3, using its class method

```
+ (AVURLAsset *)URLAssetWithURL:(NSURL *)URL options:(NSDictionary *)options
```